# Razor @onclick is Not Working When the Page is Using URL Parameters in Blazor App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I've run into an issue in a Blazor project. When I pass in URL parameters, the @onlick events are no longer working. I'm creating .cshtml pages and populating them with Razor components.

The following code does NOT work:

```
@page "/workspace/{WorkSpaceId}"
...cshtml page code
```

This code works perfectly fine:

```
@page "/workspace"
...cshtml page code
```

Components are rendered like so:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Header>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Why does adding the URL parameter cause such an issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `blazor.server.js` could be loaded successfully,or your component would be rendered as a static page in prerendering，if you switch the render mode to RenderMode.Server , the component would be blank.

I tried to reproduce the issue,

add the script without `base` taghelper

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

when I add the `{WorkSpaceId}` section,the static file path conflicts with other page and got the error in console:

[image]

A minimal example that could work based on the .net 7 BlazorServer template:

```
    @page "/workspace/{workspaceId}"
    @model IndexModel
    @{
    }
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <base href="~/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="BlazorNet7.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Server))
    
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    
    </body>
```

[image]